# Serialize class's ToString() value as XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

In C#, I'm trying to serialize ClassA into XML:

```
[Serializable]
public ClassA 
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string PropertyA { get; set; } // works fine

    [XmlElement]
    public ClassB MyClassB { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public ClassB
{
    private string _value;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the serialized result is:

```
<PropertyA>Value</PropertyA>
<ClassB />
```

Instead, I want it to be:

```
<PropertyA>Value</PropertyA>
<ClassB>Test</ClassB>
```

...assuming `_value == "Test"`.  How do I do this?  Do I *have* to provide a public property in ClassB for `_value`?  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

By implementing the IXmlSerializable interface in ClassB ([shown here](http://devolutions.net/articles/dot-net/Net-Serialization-FAQ.aspx#S23) #12), the following XML is generated:

```
<PropertyA>Value</PropertyA>
<ClassB>
    <Value>Test</Value>
</ClassB>
```

This solution is almost acceptable, but it would be nice to get rid of the  tags.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you indicated, the only way to do this is to implement the IXmlSerializable interface.

```
public class ClassB : IXmlSerializable
{
    private string _value;

    public string Value {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        _value = reader.ReadString();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteString(_value);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Serializing the following instance...

```
ClassB classB = new ClassB() { Value = "this class's value" };
```

will return the following xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><ClassB>this class's value</ClassB>
```

You might want to do some validations so that you encode xml tags etc.

Comment: Ahh, you've shown me the problem!  I was using `WriteElementString("Value", _value)` instead of `WriteString(_value)`.  Now my XML looks the way I want it: `<ClassB>Test</ClassB>`

Answer (score 3):

You've answered yourself.
if you derive from IXmlSerializable, you can change the method to do exactly (hopefully) what you wish:

```
    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
         writer.WriteElementString("ClassB",_value);
    }
```

Comment: That code produces: 

`<ClassB><ClassB>Test</ClassB></ClassB>`

when I'd really like:

`<ClassB>Test<ClassB>`

Comment: so, you can use WriteString instead of WriteElementString :-). *edit* - just saw someone else said the same :-(